# Difference from derived column in sql

Tags: mysql

I have a query. I add two column values to one derived column then I want to take the difference from the derived column and already existing column. 
But I'm getting some unknown column error

```
 SELECT  `st_id` ,  `fee` , SUM(  `total` ) AS total, SUM(  `books` ) AS book,SUM(  `uniform` ) AS uniform,SUM(  `total` + `books` + `uniform` ) AS amount,SUM(  `amount` - `paid` ) AS pending
  FROM  `fee_tbl` 
  WHERE  `st_id` 
  IN ( 40, 504, 533, 640, 817, 944 ) 
  GROUP BY  `fee` ,  `st_id`
```

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: You can not use alias on another calculation unless its from a derived query. You need to use the `sum(sum(total)+sum(books)+...) as amount` and so for others.

Comment: I dont get it.Plz give an explanation

Comment: In this case wht we do..?

Comment: You have first `SUM(  total ) AS total`, here `total` is an alias of the sum and you can not directly use that in another calculation, you have to use the complete statement again.. for `SUM(  total + books + uniform )` you need to replace `total` with `sum(total)` and so on for others since you already created an alias `total`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `amount` and `pending` for a particular `fee` and `st_id`

Then

```
SELECT  
    `st_id` ,  
    `fee` , 
    SUM(  `total` ) AS total, 
    SUM(  `books` ) AS book,
    SUM(  `uniform` ) AS uniform,
    SUM(  `total` + `books` + `uniform` ) AS amount,
    SUM(  `total` + `books` + `uniform` - `paid` ) AS pending
FROM  `fee_tbl` 
WHERE  `st_id` IN ( 40, 504, 533, 640, 817, 944 ) 
GROUP BY  `fee` ,  `st_id`
```

or

```
SELECT  
    `st_id` ,  
    `fee` , 
    SUM(  `total` ) AS total, 
    SUM(  `books` ) AS book,
    SUM(  `uniform` ) AS uniform,
    SUM(  `total` ) + SUM(  `books` ) + SUM(  `uniform` ) AS amount,
    SUM(  `total` ) + SUM(  `books` ) + SUM(  `uniform` ) - SUM(`paid` ) AS pending
FROM  `fee_tbl` 
WHERE  `st_id` IN ( 40, 504, 533, 640, 817, 944 ) 
GROUP BY  `fee` ,  `st_id`
```